# Custom Styling of Misspelled Words in Webkit with CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'd like to use a more subtle dashed line instead of the squiggles, which I've seen done somewhere but cannot find now. Has anyone done this, or does anyone know how to do this? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way to style the spellchecking marks with CSS. While not exactly what you asked for, you can add the `spellcheck="true/false"` attribute to `input` elements to enable/disable default spellchecking.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=spellcheck-attribute

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding spellcheck="true" *disables* the default spellchecking?

Comment: @Slapbox Corrected