# How to style misspelled text like Weather.com (Dashed underline instead of squiggle)

Tags: html, css, sass

Weather.com is the only example I know of that is doing this, showing a dashed red line under misspelled text instead of squiggles. This is on Chrome in Windows 7

**What I'd like to replicate**
[image]

Any ideas on how this is done? Unfortunately going to inspector clears text from the field.

**What most sites show**
[image]

Comment: pretty sure that's a feature of your browser, not their website

Comment: This is not how misspelled text appears on any other site on the entire web for me.

Comment: Just add a spelling script and it will do that automatically. Else this is done by the browser based on the language you have set .. at least Windows do that :)

Comment: Doesn't happen for me http://i.imgur.com/pBj2MI4.png (mac/chrome)

Comment: It shows squiggles on my Chrome/Windows 10

Comment: @MichaelCoker No no ... Mac can't do that, its a Windows feature :)

Comment: @LGSon right so it's coming from the browser, not the website I'm assuming. I tried on firefox, safari and chrome, no squigglies.

Comment: @MichaelCoker That is correct :)

Comment: I've added an example of what every other site looks like on my install of Chrome. If it is a browser feature, then the question becomes how to make use of it.

Comment: It seems you cannot change the style of misspelled words in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256276/custom-styling-of-misspelled-words-in-webkit-with-css

Comment: I'm aware of that question, I asked it. But here is proof that it is possible to do... Somehow... Unless Chrome is hard-coded to behave this way on Weather.com which seems pretty unlikely..

Comment: Well, as I said, on my Chrome/Windows 10 there is no _dashed red line_, so _Weather.com_ can obviously not control that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to not be a style, but rather an effect of a precisely sized text box/precisely tuned line height. The squiggle is 2px tall, but the bottom 1px was cut off, giving it the appearance of a dashed line, but in fact it is not.

This method can be used to replicate the effect shown **IF** you are using a font where the letters that extend below the baseline don't go so far down that they touch the spellcheck squiggle.

It seems possible to move the squiggle independently of the text, which could possibly present a way to do emulate this style with any font.

If I find a way to do this, I will update further.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *browser feature* that can be achieved (at least in Webkit/Blink) on input fields and contentEditable elements with `spellcheck="true"`. Not every browser will implement it the same way. For that, you would have to build the text markers yourself in conjunction with a dictionary service (like Google Docs does, as one example).

https://jsfiddle.net/bn7pfyf3/

(change the "true"s to "false"s and you won't see any highlights on focus)

---

In Webkit/Blink, this is a DocumentMarker type (which is used for Ctrl+F, highlights, typos in input fields, and more). They are not exposed in the DOM or CSS.
https://github.com/crosswalk-project/blink-crosswalk/blob/master/Source/core/dom/DocumentMarker.h